# Failing to install graphlab

Tags: python, pip, graphlab

l am using this  command :

pip install --upgrade --no-cache-dir https://get.graphlab.com/GraphLab-Create/2.1/my email address/Product key/GraphLab-Create-License.tar.gz which is provided at the Turi website. l have followed the instructions of creating the virtual env but it still doesnt work

But l get the below error

```
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement graphlab-create>=2.1 (from GraphLab-Create-License==2.1) (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for graphlab-create>=2.1 (from GraphLab-Create-License==2.1)
```

Comment: Are you using python 2.7? Are you able to download the .tar.gz using e.g. `wget`?

Comment: l'm using python 3.7 and cant download it

Comment: "GraphLab Create installation requires a Python 2.7.x environment" <-- this is the very first sentence in the [installation instructions](https://turi.com/download/install-graphlab-create-command-line.html). Try creating a python 2.7 environment

Comment: @FlyingTeller thanks , l dont know how l missed that

Comment: My installation was successfuk following this link
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61720574/graphlab-installation-when-python-2-7-is-no-longer-supported/62167416#62167416